# Open UITableView edit action buttons programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UIPageViewController` that have `UITableViewControllers` inside it, and the swipe left gestures are conflicted between the `UIPageViewController` to change between the views and the `UITableViewCells` gesture to open the edit actions, so I need to show the edit actions when a certain button is clicked in the cell.

My question is can I show the edit action buttons programmatically instead of showing them on the swipe gesture?

Comment: I faced the same problem too, did you get any solution?
please share it with us.

Comment: @eng_rawan Actully no this issue is still pending.

Comment: Did you find any solution? @Firas

Comment: @MouhamadKawas No actually, this issue is still open.

Comment: Not getting question properly!! What is the exact need? Want to delete cell on button click  or anything else?

Comment: As far as I know, `UITableView` doesn't expose any methods to do this, so your best bet may be to just use a framework like [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell) or to follow a tutorial such as [this one](https://www.raywenderlich.com/62435/make-swipeable-table-view-cell-actions-without-going-nuts-scroll-views).

Comment: **Update**: I think that I've found the (private) functions that initiate the swipe, I'll probably be able to create a framework-less answer in a few hours once I have the time

Comment: I have tried all of the answers here and they do not work in Xcode 9 / iOS 10. I have seen over a dozen posts in on stack overflow over the last year that ask for this functionality and all are unanswered or reference this one, which also doesn't have an answer. I hope someone can find a solution soon.

Comment: I've tried many solutions but none of them work. As a result I used @kabiroberai's solution. I also want to know framework-less solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apple has a private API that lets you do this, however, be warned that this may get your app rejected from the App Store unless you obfuscate the usage of said API using something like *Method Swizzling*. Here are the steps to do so:

1. Create a protocol called `PrivateMethodRevealer` that lets you access the required private Apple APIs, namely the ones to show and dismiss edit actions. Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38108583/3769927) for providing this method of exposing private APIs. The methods in the protocol are declared as `optional`, so that in case Apple changes the name of the method, the app will not crash, but rather, it'll just not show the edit actions.

   ```
   @objc protocol PrivateMethodRevealer {
       optional func setShowingDeleteConfirmation(arg1: Bool)
       optional func _endSwipeToDeleteRowDidDelete(arg1: Bool)
   }
   ```

   Note that although the methods refer to `delete`, this shows all the `UITableViewRowAction`s that are on the cell.
2. Create a function that handles the showing and hiding of the edit actions in your `UITableViewCell` subclass (if you have one), or create the method in a `UITableViewCell` `extension`. I will name this method `showActions` for demonstrative purposes.
3. Add the following body to your function:

   ```
   func showActions() {
       (superview?.superview as? AnyObject)?._endSwipeToDeleteRowDidDelete?(false)
       (self as AnyObject).setShowingDeleteConfirmation?(true)
   }
   ```

   This firstly dismisses any visible cells' editing actions, by calling `_endSwipeToDeleteRowDidDelete:` on the `UITableView` (which is the cell's superview's superview), and then shows the cell's own editing actions (by calling `setShowingDeleteConfirmation:`). Note that we need to dismiss other cells' actions as showing multiple rows with edit actions is extremely buggy.
4. If you want, you may also create a button in the `UIViewController` that dismisses any currently editing cells. To do this, just call the following method, where `tableView` is your reference to the `UITableView`:

   ```
   (tableView as AnyObject)?._endSwipeToDeleteRowDidDelete?(false)
   ```

If the swipe gestures between your `UIPageViewController` and `UITableViewCell`s are conflicting, simply override the `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` method to return `.None`.

In the end, your code might produce the following result
[image: Demo video]

**EDIT**: Here is a quick way to hide the usage of your API using method swizzling. Credits to [this website](https://www.uraimo.com/2015/10/23/effective-method-swizzling-with-swift/) for providing the basic implementation of this method. Be warned that I can't guarantee that it'll work, as it isn't possible to test it live.

To do this, replace the protocols with the following code, and wherever you call `setShowingDeleteConfirmation(true)` or `_endSwipeToDeleteRowDidDelete(false)`, replace it with `showRowActions()` and `hideRowActions()` instead. This method appears to have some unintended effects however, such as the `UITableViewCell`s not responding to user interaction whilst edit actions are visible.

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func showRowActions(arg1: Bool = true) {}

    public override static func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        guard self === UITableViewCell.self else {return}

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            let hiddenString = String(":noitamrifnoCeteleDgniwohStes".characters.reverse())
            let originalSelector = NSSelectorFromString(hiddenString)
            let swizzledSelector = #selector(showRowActions(_:))
            let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
            let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)
            class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }
    }
}

extension UITableView {
    func hideRowActions(arg1: Bool = false) {}

    public override static func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
        }

        guard self === UITableView.self else {return}

        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            let hiddenString = String(":eteleDdiDwoReteleDoTepiwSdne_".characters.reverse())
            let originalSelector = NSSelectorFromString(hiddenString)
            let swizzledSelector = #selector(hideRowActions(_:))
            let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector)
            let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector)
            class_addMethod(self, originalSelector, method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod), method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod))
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, beat my by a day.  Nice reference to my question too.  I would not recommend having one global protocol that `NSObject`/`AnyObject` conforms to.  Consider two separate protocols and use of `unsafeBitCast` as seen in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39147692/2415822).

Comment: @JAL although it may seem dangerous to use one protocol, the beauty of `optional` protocols is that if the object doesn't conform to the protocol, it just fails silently. This may also happen in the case of the name of the method being changed, so it kills two birds with one stone (i.e. you don't need to call `respondsToSelector:`).

Comment: @JAL also, if you see the answer that I have linked, it explains that `unsafeBitCast`s are inherently _unsafe_. If the method doesn't exist for some reason, the app will crash.

Comment: Of course I read the answer, it's my question.  And yes, all of this is unsafe, but we know those methods are implemented by the classes, so there's no harm in `unsafeBitCast`.  If you wanted to be more safe, use optional protocols and check for the selectors of course.  For small prototyping `unsafeBitCast` is sufficient.

Comment: @JAL oh sorry, I somehow missed the fact that you had asked the linked question  xD

Comment: @JAL if you really want to go the `unsafeBitCast` way, I think that you should at least implement a `performsSelector` check, just in case a later version of iOS refactors the method.

Comment: I'll make an note in my answer.

Comment: @naohta please do not add new code to other users' answer.  We don't want to put words in their mouths.  Instead, add a comment (with sufficient reputation) or a new answer.

Comment: I tried both different examples, protocol + swizzling. Doesn't work for me in Xcode 9 / iOS 10, can you confirm it works for you?

Comment: Guyz to call directly HIdden API is safe way to achieve above objective. Does apple will reject the application due to this?

Answer (score 0):

I was on the same path as kabiroberai in finding a solution to this answer, but took a different approach with two separate protocols rather than one Objective-C/NSObject protocol that could potentially be misused.  This also prevents having to make the protocol methods optional.

First, create two separate protocols to expose the private methods on both the `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell`.  I found these by digging through the [private headers](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers) of each class.

```
@objc protocol UITableViewCellPrivate {
    func setShowingDeleteConfirmation(arg1: Bool)
}

@objc protocol UITableViewPrivate {
    func _endSwipeToDeleteRowDidDelete(arg1: Bool)
}
```

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, keep a reference to the cell (or multiple cells) which you want to show the edit actions for:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var cell: UITableViewCell?

    // ...

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")!

       // ...        

        if indexPath.row == 1 {
            self.cell = cell
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Now, fire the private methods.  I used `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`, or you can use a button.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()    
    self.performSelector(#selector(showActionsForCell), withObject: nil, afterDelay: 2.0)
}

func showActionsForCell() {

    if let cell = cell {
        let cellPrivate = unsafeBitCast(cell, UITableViewCellPrivate.self)
        let tableViewPrivate = unsafeBitCast(self.tableView, UITableViewPrivate.self)

        // Dismiss any other edit actions that are open
        tableViewPrivate._endSwipeToDeleteRowDidDelete(false)

        // Open the edit actions for the selected cell
        cellPrivate.setShowingDeleteConfirmation(true)
    }
}
```

Calling `unsafeBitCast` directly is dangerous.  For safety, check if your `UITableView` and `UITableViewCell` respond to those selectors, or make the functions optional.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the argument in `_endSwipeToDeleteRowDidDelete:` refers to whether the row was deleted, not whether it should end the swipe.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Xcode 9 / iOS 10, can you confirm it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

In my case (swift 3, iOS11) [MGSwipeTableCell](https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell) works perfect. You can configure call's buttons in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: prettyIdentifier, for: indexPath)

    cell.allowsButtonsWithDifferentWidth = true
    cell.rightButtons = [MGSwipeButton(title: "Delete\npermanently", backgroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9745360017, green: 0.7205639482, blue: 0.3932176828, alpha: 1)), MGSwipeButton(title: "Undo",backgroundColor: .black)]
    cell.rightSwipeSettings.transition = .rotate3D
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}
```

instead of

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {...}
```

and catch touches in

```
extension RecordingViewController: MGSwipeTableCellDelegate {
    func swipeTableCell(_ cell: MGSwipeTableCell, tappedButtonAt index: Int, direction: MGSwipeDirection, fromExpansion: Bool) -> Bool {
        cell.hideSwipe(animated: true)
        // do your stuff here like
        if index == 0 {
            print("right button")
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Set the table view Editing with an IBAction or other method:

```
@IBAction func editOn(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
}
```

You can use the methods from UITableViewController:

```
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // Return false if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return true
}
```

And this method is the actions for editing:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let action = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete") { (rowAction: UITableViewRowAction, indexPAth: NSIndexPath) in
        //code for delete
        print("Delete")
    }
    let action2 = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Share") { (rowAction: UITableViewRowAction, indexPAth: NSIndexPath) in
        //code for share
        print("Share")
    }
    return [action, action2]
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This adds the actions, but doesn't show how to make them visible programmatically.

Answer (score -4):

On your button click event, could you please try with below function.

```
func setEditing(_ editing: Bool,
   animated animated: Bool)
```

This is function is in the swift syntax.

As per the [Apple developer support](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/setEditing:animated:) website it will do the following things,

> When you call this method with the value of editing set to true, and
>   the UITableViewCell object is configured to have controls, the cell
>   shows an insertion (green plus) or deletion control (red minus) on the
>   left side of each cell and a reordering control on the right side.
>   This method is called on each visible cell when the
>   setEditing:animated: method of UITableView is invoked. Calling this
>   method with editing set to false removes the controls from the cell.

Hope this answers the question.

Comment: I did try that function, but unfortunately it didn't work.