# How do I expose a private class method of an Objective-C object using protocols in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uicolor, swift-protocols

Consider two private methods on `UIColor`:

1. The instance method `styleString` which returns the RGB string of the color
2. The class method `_systemDestructiveTintColor` which returns the red color used by destructive buttons.

[UIColor.h private header for reference](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIColor.h)

For instance methods, I can create an `@objc` protocol and use `unsafeBitCast` to expose the private method:

```
@objc protocol  UIColorPrivate {
    func styleString() -> UIColor
}

let white = UIColor.whiteColor()
let whitePrivate = unsafeBitCast(white, UIColorPrivate.self)
whitePrivate.styleString() // rgb(255,255,255)
```

However, I'm not sure how this would work for class methods.

First attempt:

```
@objc protocol UIColorPrivate {
    class func _systemDestructiveTintColor() -> String // Error: Class methods are only allowed within classes
}
```

Makes sense, I'll change it to `static`:

```
@objc protocol UIColorPrivate {
    static func _systemDestructiveTintColor() -> String
}

let colorClass = UIColor.self
let privateClass = unsafeBitCast(colorClass, UIColorPrivate.self) // EXC_BAD_ACCESS
```

This causes a crash.  Well this is going nowhere fast.  I could use a bridging header and just expose the class methods as an `@interface`, but is there a way to expose these private class methods in pure Swift?

I could do this with `performSelector`, but I'd rather expose the method as an interface or protocol:

```
if UIColor.respondsToSelector("_systemDestructiveTintColor") {
    if let red = UIColor.performSelector("_systemDestructiveTintColor").takeUnretainedValue() as? UIColor {
        // use the color
    }
}
```

Comment: @matt your comment is not constructive.  I'm asking for an alternative using protocols (added that detail back to the title).

Comment: It _is_ constructive. `performSelector` is a perfectly good way to do this. I use it for this myself.

Comment: Can you `unsafeBitCast` an instance of `UIColor` then call the method with `instance.dynamicType._systemDesctructiveTintColor()`?

Comment: @dan I don't think that would work, since behind-the-scenes `UIColor` is treated as `UICachedDeviceRGBColor`.  Try it yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want via protocols is to use a separate protocol for the static method. Static methods in `Objective-C` are actually instance methods on the metaclass of the class, so you can safely take an approach like below:

```
@objc protocol UIColorPrivateStatic {
    func _systemDestructiveTintColor() -> UIColor
}

let privateClass = UIColor.self as! UIColorPrivateStatic
privateClass._systemDestructiveTintColor() // UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 1 0.231373 0.188235 1
```

This will give you both exposure of the private method and usage of protocols, and you get rid of the ugly `unsafeBitCast` (not that a forced cast would be more beautiful).

Just note that as always if you are working with private API's your code can break at any time if Apple decides to change some of the internals of the class.

Comment: Thanks Cristik, good to see you active again.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  It's weird that the force downcast works but not `unsafeBitCast`.  But this answer the question.

Comment: The forced downcast is unnecessary and is a red herring. Just cast to AnyObject. You can send any known Objective-C message to AnyObject, and the protocol makes it known. This is exactly what I was getting at in the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @JAL it might have to do with the way `unsafeBitCast` works, my assumption is that `as` does a simply pointer conversion for `Objective-C` objects,  while `unsafeBitCast` tries to do more - Kevin has a very good technical description about the internals of that function.

Comment: @matt that's true, but the protocol cast get's us nicer and more type-safe code (even if  `safe` is relative in this context)

Answer (score 3):

> but is there a way to expose these private class methods

That's like saying you want a vegan meal consisting of steak. You can have the steak, but that would not be a vegan meal. The words "private" and "expose" are opposites.

Using Objective-C's dynamic messaging solves the problem. You can use it by way of `performSelector` and its family of methods. You already know this, so it's hard to see what more can be wanted.

If you prefer to use `#selector` syntax, you can create a dummy `class` protocol with a `static` method containing your target function, to give yourself a way to refer to the method. Your whole `unsafeBitCast` route, however, is going nowhere.

**EDIT** You can send any known message to any Objective-C object by casting to AnyObject, and you can use my dummy `class` protocol to make the message known:

```
@objc protocol Dummy {
    func hiddenMethod()
}
(someObject as AnyObject).hiddenMethod()
```

But I don't see why this is better than the protocol and `#selector` syntax.

Comment: So why can I use an Objective-C protocol to expose instance methods but not class methods?

Answer (score 3):

`unsafeBitCast()` is a terrible way to access private API.

> is there a way to expose these private class methods in pure Swift?

There is an answer to **that** question - use an extension with a computed property. You still have to use perform selector but you get the type safety.

```
extension UIColor {
    static var systemDestructiveTintColor: UIColor {
        let privateColor = Selector("_systemDestructiveTintColor")
        if UIColor.respondsToSelector(privateColor),
            let red = UIColor.performSelector(privateColor).takeUnretainedValue() as? UIColor {
                return red
            }
        return UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let color = UIColor.systemDestructiveTintColor
print(color)
```

### Update - breaking down unsafebit cast

To address the question in the comments:

> then why would they expose the unsafeBitCast API in the first place?

The documentation for `unsafeBitCast()` says the following:

> - Warning: Breaks the guarantees of Swift's type system; use with extreme care. There's almost always a better way to do anything.

`unsafeBitCast` is defined in [swift/stdlib/public/core/Builtin.swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2807a17eb894f7e24af7c26ccbe090e0ed446bb9/stdlib/public/core/Builtin.swift) as

```
@_transparent
public func unsafeBitCast<T, U>(_ x: T, to: U.Type) -> U {
  _precondition(sizeof(T.self) == sizeof(U.self),
    "can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes")
  return Builtin.reinterpretCast(x)
}
```

`Builtin.reinterpretCast` is defined in [swift/include/swift/AST/Builtins.def](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/878134b1d5feec3997e0422963a176ac7ff60cc6/include/swift/AST/Builtins.def) as

```
/// reinterpretCast has type T -> U.
BUILTIN_SIL_OPERATION(ReinterpretCast, "reinterpretCast", Special)
```

`ReinterpretCast` is the C++ identifier, `"reinterpretCast"` is the string name in Swift and `Special` is an attribute of the function which means the following ([source](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/82509cbd7451e72fb99d22556ad259ceb335cb1f/include/swift/AST/Builtins.h)):

> The builtin has custom proccessing

So where is that custom processing? In [swift/lib/AST/Builtins.cpp](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/9cb793c69b763e00ff19b808bbee140240e97c7f/lib/AST/Builtins.cpp)

```
case BuiltinValueKind::ReinterpretCast:
  if (!Types.empty()) return nullptr;
  return getReinterpretCastOperation(Context, Id);
...
...
static ValueDecl *getReinterpretCastOperation(ASTContext &ctx,
                                              Identifier name) {
  // <T, U> T -> U
  // SILGen and IRGen check additional constraints during lowering.
  GenericSignatureBuilder builder(ctx, 2);
  builder.addParameter(makeGenericParam(0));
  builder.setResult(makeGenericParam(1));
  return builder.build(name);
}
```

#### Summary

The purpose of unsafe bit cast is to blindly change a type of 1 object to another. The protocol instance method just happens to work because if you treat the bits of `@objc protocol  UIColorPrivate { func styleString() -> UIColor }` like it was `UIColor.styleString() -> UIColor` the correct method is called.

It's not at all strange that it doesn't work with class methods; in fact i'd say it's miraculous that it works for instance methods.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using `performSelector`directly.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using `performSelector:`? That's a fine tool. You're breaking the API contract already. Why is `performSelector:` the line you're worried about crossing? You could create an ObjC category (in a `.h` file imported through the ObjC bridge) that exposes the method and import it, which would avoid the `performSelector:`, but that's even more work.

Comment: @RobNapier it's not about going into API unsafe territory.  Why can I use a protocol to expose instance methods but not class methods?  This method is already on UIColor, ideally I wouldn't have to call `performSelector` to implement it.  I've already mentioned that this is possible through a bridging header but I'm looking for an implementation in pure Swift.

Comment: This is entirely about going outside the API. Swift doesn't have explicit support for exposing things that aren't private. The fact that you occasionally get away with it is the surprise, not the cases where it *doesn't* work.

Comment: But to your original question, you may be totally right, in which case the correct thing is to open a radar asking that Swift not allow you to expose private instance methods this way so that it be consistent.

Comment: @RobNapier If Swift "doesn't have explicit support" for this, then why would they expose the `unsafeBitCast` API in the first place?  I'm not trying to use any of this in production code, I'm just trying to understand why this behavior occurs, and if the behavior I'm asking for is possible with Swift's unsafe APIs.

Comment: Almost anything involving unsafeBitcast requires explicit understanding of how Swift types are implanted under the covers and is completely implementation dependent. You've discovered a difference in how NSObject subclasses are bridged to Swift vs how metaclasses are bridged. Classes and metaclasses aren't the same. Once you've gone off-road with unsafeBitcast, knowledge of the compiler details are your problem. It mostly exists for use inside stdlib (which evolves with the compiler). That something happens to work doesn't mean it's supported or promised.

Comment: @JAL I investigated why they expose `unsafeBitCast` and what it actually does