# Swift iOS show UITableView edit actions on button tap?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In my custom tableView cell design, there is a "more" button on the right side that is intended to trigger the cell's edit actions. I was wondering if it was possible to show the UITableViewRowActions I've specified in editActionsForRowAt by clicking a button as well as by swiping?

So far I tried:

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: sender.tag, section: 0))?.setEditing(true, animated: true)
```

But this didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open UITableView edit action buttons programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543832/open-uitableview-edit-action-buttons-programmatically)