# How to show tableview cell edit view when tap the cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, ipad

My requirement is show the tableviewcell edit view when tap the cell. The "editActionsForRowAtIndexPath" is working when swipe but i want this action when tap the cell.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4cSA.png)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39129283/4637057

Comment: What you actually mean by "tableviewcell edit view " ?? Do you want to show edit action button or you want to make cell contents editable?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you use for swipe. But if you want to handle some actions when the user tap the cell you should use didSelectRowAtIndexPath function. For example;

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Tapped")
}
```

Comment: My requirement is edit tableview cell on TAP instead of swipe.


See the effect :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCoUS.gif

 I want this effect when click the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on didselect delegate method, I think it will be help you.

self.tableView.editing = true