# How to call "editActionsForRowAt" function programmatically in swift4

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, swift4

There is any way to call `editActionsForRowAt` programmatically in swift3

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

}
```

This is for:-

when user come on that screen than first row open with animation for delete option then close in 0.3 sec. Then user know that the there are delete option on swipe

Comment: can you try this example http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/uitableviewrowaction-example-in-swift/

Comment: thanx bro, but I want to call that with programmatically

Comment: why do yo uneed to do that? it is not recommended

Comment: sir when user come on that screen than first row open with animation for delete option then close in 0.3 sec.

Comment: sir when user come on that screen than first row open with animation for delete option then close in 0.3 sec. Then user know that the there are delete option on swipe

Comment: @BijenderSinghShekhawat Apple has a private API that lets you do this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543832/open-uitableview-edit-action-buttons-programmatically
 But simply you can try this also to show editing mode : 
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
            self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)
        }