# Simulate left drag of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewrowaction

My goal is to indicate to first time users that the cells on my tableview are editable. To show this, my goal is to animate a slight left drag.

Outside of programmatically generating touch events, I was unsure whether its possible to achieve something like this using `UITableViewRowAction`

For example, here is my following implementation for the full drag events:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

        if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Allow") { (rowAction, indexPath) in

                tableView.beginUpdates()
                //...implementation methods not included for brevity 
                tableView.endUpdates() 
            }
            editAction.backgroundColor = DisplayColors.AllViews.WarnColor
            return [editAction]
        } 
}
```

However, the above only works for when the user physically drags the cell. I don't know if there is a way to call this programmatically just to demonstrate that the cell has this ability.

Comment: Apple has a private API that lets you do this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543832/open-uitableview-edit-action-buttons-programmatically
But simply you can try this also to show editing mode : 
  self.tableView.setEditing(true, animated: true)