# Swift call specific row editActions programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to trigger editAction with my custom cell button.

I have tried to implement a delegate to call `tableView.isEditing  = true` , but I just want to show editAtion menu of specific cell.

Anyone has idea to show editActions with indexPath?

Comment: look - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543832/open-uitableview-edit-action-buttons-programmatically

Comment: [Check this stack over flow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164188/custom-edit-view-in-uitableviewcell-while-swipe-left-objective-c-or-swift). [Check this site](http://vinsol.com/blog/2015/01/06/custom-edit-control-for-uitableviewcell/). There is a lot of lib file available check those too. Next share what you tried?

Comment: @Jack I've tried, but the objc method trigger exception. @ user3589771 I want to control the edit action, not create