# How to show editActionsForRowAtIndexPath's buttons of UITableviewCell on cell click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have used `editActionsForRowAtIndexPath` to add custom `UITableViewRowAction`.

I want to auto drag to show this two option(`Delete` & `Cancel`) by just to click `UITableViewCell` (didSelectRowAtIndexPath).

Currently dragging cell from right to left is working but how can I show this without dragging(by just clicking any button on cell),

Is there any method to show this option of a particular cell.

eg.

[image]

My Code:

```
-(NSArray<UITableViewRowAction *> *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     UITableViewRowAction *deleteAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Delete" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
            // delete action
     }];
     deleteAction.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

     UITableViewRowAction *cancelAction = [UITableViewRowAction rowActionWithStyle:UITableViewRowActionStyleNormal title:@"Cancel" handler:^(UITableViewRowAction *action, NSIndexPath *indexPath){
       //cancel action
     }];


     return @[deleteAction, cancelAction];
}
```

Note: without using custom design.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open UITableView edit action buttons programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543832/open-uitableview-edit-action-buttons-programmatically)

Comment: Try call on cell `setEditing:YES animated:YES`